# Relevance to compile several js files in one for a production site

Tags: javascript, apache, frontend

I have ten `js` files used in different pages of my website but never all together.

Is it possible to compile all `js` files into a single file?

I wish to avoid that the client browser has to load several `js` files.

How would I achieve this and what is the best practice in terms of loading performance?

Comment: Why don't you measure the performance of both approaches yourself?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using an AMD module loader such as [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/). It has the capability to concat and uglify all your scripts into one file so it downloads everything in a single request.

If you do not want to use AMD modules, you could just concat and minimize your files manually. Minimizing is mainly done to compress your code and to obfuscate the source, even though there are tools to reverse the minimized code. Have a look at [Google's closure compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/) and [UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2).

Another thing you could to is to make your web server gzip it's responses for `application/javascript` MIME type.

Answer (score 0):

Really worth looking at Grunt, and specifically [grunt concat task](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat)

This is just one way Grunt is helpful, very much worth your time to get your head around!

There are also plugins for Require, which is very helpful.